# How can I create a one-to-one relationship between two loops in bash?

Tags: bash

In a bash script, I want to create a one-to-one relationship between two for loops that each have variables defined as a sequence. For example, I want something like

```
for g in `seq 11 1 21`;do
for i in `seq 1 1 10`;do
cat >$i.txt  <<EOF
this one is $g.
EOF
done
done
```

to result in ten files (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, etc). 1.txt would contain "this one is 11." 2.txt would contain "this one is 12." Etc.

The above example is permutative, where each value of g acts on each value of i. Is there a way to make it so only one value of g acts on only one value of i in a corresponding order (ie 1 corresponds to 11, 2 corresponds to 12, etc)?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr1=( $(seq 11 21 ))
arr2=( $(seq 1 10 ))

for idx in $(seq 0 ${#arr2[*]})
do
  file="/tmp/"${arr2[$idx]}".txt"
  echo "This one is ${arr1[$idx]} "  > $file
done
```

First,both the sequences are assigned to 2 arrays. And then as you iterate over the length of 2nd array, you frame the string and write to file.

Comment: You really are a Guru. It worked perfectly. Thank you so, so much.

Comment: I am glad this answer helped you. You can choose to accept it.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Before I answer, there's a critical problem with the question: the two sequences have different lengths (there are eleven `g` values, but only ten `i` values). Either one of `g`'s values must be skipped, or something filled in as the extra value for `i`. For my answer I'll assume `g` should actually run from 11 to 20, not 21.

If you don't want all combinations, then you only want one loop; the trick is to make a single loop iterate through both sequences simultaneously. There are a couple of ways to do this in bash. One is to store both sequences as arrays, and then iterate over their indexes:

```
g_array=( {11..20} )   # Could also use g_array=( $(seq 11 1 20) ) here
i_array=( {1..10} )
for index in "${!g_array[@]}"; do    # The ${!arr[2]} gets the *indexes* of the array
    cat >"${i_array[index]}.txt"  <<EOF
this one is ${g_array[index]}.
EOF
done
```

Alternately, since these are just numeric sequences, you can use the `for ((init; test; step))` structure to do it:

```
for ((g=11,i=1; g<=20; g++,i++)); do    # Note: semicolons between parts, commas between things that happen together
    cat >"$i.txt"  <<EOF
this one is $g.
EOF
done
```